# Angularjs formdata with array field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, form-data

Hi i am editing data on which my all my data gets edited except array, object .. i somehow managed to pass object data but for array i am getting comma separated value in Server (Nodejs)..Pls check an help

Angularjs

```
                    angular.forEach(pushdata.product, function(value, key) {

                    if (key == 'img_path') {
                        // for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        fd.append('img_path', value);
                        //}
                    } else if (key == 'vehicle_details') {
                        angular.forEach(value, function(value, key) {
                            fd.append('vehicle_details.' + key, value);
                        });
                    } else {
                        fd.append(key, value);
                    }
                });
```

When i am POSTing this data to server i get String containing values of array each separeted by comma .. like this "11,22,33"

Server(Node)

```
form.on('field', function(field, Fdata) {
    if (field == 'img_path') {
        console.log(Fdata); // logs "11,22,33"
        for (var i = 0; i < Fdata.length; i++) {
            img_attr['img_path'].push(Fdata[i]);
        }
    } else {
        img_attr[field] = Fdata;
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a string into an array containing data, you could do the following:

```
var arr = Fdata.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseFloat(arr[i]);
}
```

*After executing this code on your server, `arr` will contain all the values you initially sent.*